# position of div/classes when responsive from line to block

Tags: html, css

so seems simple enough yet i can't for the life of me figure out how to order the map and the info container within the container so they are in column form instead of row form , (for a mobile version) can anyone help here is the html and css...

```
<!-- content -->
<div id="container-map">

<div id="map">
    <div class="map animated bounceInRight">
</div>
<div class="info-side animated bounceInRight">
    <div id="accordion1">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>Heading 2</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 3</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <h1>Heading 30</h1>
            <div>
                <span>Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna. Cras scelerisque risus eget odio interdum consequat.
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

and the css

```
.map{float:left; background: url(../img/map-1309.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; display:inline-block; height:700px;width:45%;}
.info-side{float:left; overflow-y:scroll;height:400px; margin-left:10px;}
#container-map{padding:30px 0; clear:both;top:100px; z-index:10;position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;margin-left:200px;}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: instead of one div next to eachother i want them to be in a column so i can make a mobile version , so map needs to be top , then side-info directly belwo it

Comment: That's already the case?

Comment: nope they are next to eachother currently

Comment: Take a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/dorjvw

Comment: thanks for your patience , i kinda got it to work , the accordian has dependencies so am looking at that now as well to perfect it thanks for the input

Comment: No problem. Let us know when you have any questions.